# Application Specific Questions - Hansen or Technology One

Tags: discussion

I'm working with a number of commecial packages - Hansen, Technology One for instance. I'm sure most sites will be in the same boat. In my case these systems are built on Sql Server and come with reasonable support but there's always a need for more questions and knowledge from other sites. I'm not sure that SO is the place for those questions - but if not where can I ask them.

As an example here's a typical question - how do I integrate a parameter driven Crystal Report into Technology One?

Answer (score 1):

Those questions are fine to ask, just tag them with the package name, **BUT** you there may not be enough users of that package to give you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is enough critical mass for a standalone stackexchange (you could start one) or another forum/site caters to it - asking the (programming-related) question here (or on ServerFault if it's more of a network/server admin thing) cannot hurt because Google gives pretty good search results from StackOverflow as long as the questions are good and tagged well - so you chances of someone hitting your question from Google are very good.

If some critical mass grows, then you could always move to a custom stack exchange later.

This initial question should probably be on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), however.